# Postgresql UPDATE to Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've been trying to convert this Postgresql UPDATE query into an ActiveRecord call on Rails.

```
  UPDATE uploads AS u
  SET organization_id = p.owner_id
  FROM projects AS p
  WHERE p.owner_type = 'Organization'
  AND p.id = u.project_id ;
```

I tried using `#update_all` but I can't work out a way to dynamically assign the value of `organization_id` without bringing the results of a SELECT into Ruby land.  On a small scale it doesn't really matter, but I'm trying to minimise the number of DB calls.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of the models, schema , data and an expected result? A more AR way would be to setup an assocation (unless you have one) and join the projects table instead of using FROM. Even if it may be possible to write that query if you get really creative its going to be hell to read (I struggled a bit with it even in SQL).